# Dynamically inspecting JavaScript module exports in a web browser console

Tags: javascript, svelte

I am [dynamically loading a module](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#dynamic_imports) as:

```js
    onMount(async () => {
        if (browser) {
            const module = await import('jquery');
            console.log("jQuery module is", module);
        }
    }
```

This module was installed using `npm install jquery` and then made available in the web browser context by the standard SvelteKit builder toolchain.

How can I inspect in the web browser JavaScript console what symbols the module exports, as the `module.default` seems to be undefined?

Module itself does not seem to offer any dynamic inspection capabilities:

```
jQuery module is  Module {Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): 'Module'} Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): "Module"
```

Comment: In this case looks like the jQuery module is not really a module and you can get the access to jQuery  by `jQuery = module`.